# Call to undefined method stdClass::count() in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, pagination

I trying to paginate my JSON response but got error like this

> Call to undefined method stdClass::count()

My JSON response from the Laravel API by using guzzle ......

here is my controller code

```php
public function index()
{
    $response =  $this->client->get('getUserIndex')->getBody();
    $content = json_decode($response->getContents());
    $total = $content->count();
    $paginationRecord = CollectionPaginate::paginate($content, $total, '15');
    return view('configuration.comuserprofiles.ComUserProfilesList', ['paginationRecord' => $paginationRecord->data]);
}
```

Comment: plz post `dd($content)`

Comment: `$content` is an object, not a collection, you cannot use `->count()` on that. You'll have to use `count($content)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$content = json_decode($response->getContents());
$total = $content->count();
```

I am not entirely sure why you think the result of json_decode would have a count method? The JSON decoding always results in a generic object (stdClass) since there's no way for the PHP interpreter to know it represents an available class.

The ->count method is available on Countable implementations (such as ArrayCollection). If you expect a Countable class, then you can either have a factory to build your object from JSON or try to cast the stdClass to ArrayCollection.

Otherwise, if your JSON data is a valid array, you can try to use

```
$decoded = json_decode($data, true)
```

meaning it will decode it to an array rather than an object, which enables you to do

```
count($decoded)
```

Comment: hi sir.. just got error like "Argument 1 passed to App\Helpers\CollectionPaginate::paginate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection, instance of stdClass given"

Comment: @adaminho Note that `$content` will either become an array or a stdClass object by json_decode but never an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. Try `$collection = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection($decoded); $paginationRecord = CollectionPaginate::paginate($collection, $total, '15');`

Comment: @jrswgtr thank you so much sir i able to pass data to view

Answer (score 3):

$content is an object, not a collection or array you can use php method count with array get $total

Please Change to

```
 public function index()
        {


            $response =  $this->client->get('getUserIndex')->getBody();
            $content = json_decode($response->getContents(),true );
            $total = count($content);
            $paginationRecord = CollectionPaginate::paginate($content, $total, '15');
            return view('configuration.comuserprofiles.ComUserProfilesList', ['paginationRecord' => $paginationRecord->data]);

}
```

Comment: hi sir.. just got error like  "Argument 1 passed to App\Helpers\CollectionPaginate::paginate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection, instance of stdClass given"

Comment: I think you need to know the response data first. may be the array is nested by another key.